# How to set focus() to an input text box that is NOT inside a form

Tags: javascript

I thought this would work:

```
...
<input type="text" id="myText" />
...
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    document.getElementById["myText"].focus();
</script>
```

Comment: try `document.getElementById("myText").focus();`  also if this happens after page load, you may need to put this in a function hooked into `window.onload`

Comment: And it should. Replace `[` and `]` with `(` and `)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user1169578 is correct, Try:

```
document.getElementById("myText").focus();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LZsc5/